# Does Glucosamine Hydrochloride help painful dog joints?

Tags: dogs, medicines, pain

We have a dog that has a pin in his hip from an accident. He is badly affected by the cold and it causes him pain in winter.

I'm wondering if Glucosamine Hydrochloride will assist in helping his joint pain.

Answer (score 2):

There is research that demonstrates the efficacy of Glucosamine Hydrochloride in relieving painful joints in our doggy companions caused by [osteoarthritis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5356289/) and [other arthritic conditions](https://www.rheumatoidarthritis.org/dogs-best-glucosamine/). It helps by preventing the degradation and stimulating growth of the cartilage around the joints. **1.**

### When it doesn't work

So if a dog has a severe arthritic condition where it is bone on bone, it will not help. **1.**

### How to dose

The key to effectiveness is achieving a therapeutic level. This is done by giving loading doses of double the maintenance dose for 4-6 weeks - which is 30mg/kg per day. The maintenance dose is then 15mg/kg per day. Split into two daily doses for larger dogs. **1.**

[image]
Image courtesy of [Rheumatoid Arthritis Org](https://www.rheumatoidarthritis.org/dogs-best-glucosamine/).

### Glucosamine Hydrochloride not Glucosamine Sulfate

Glucosamine hydrochloride is not as well absorbed as glucosamine sulfate, however it reaches the target tissue more effectively and there is evidence that it has therapeutically effective, whereas the evidence of the effectiveness of glucosamine sulfate is sparse. **1.**  So be sure to source the correct form of Glucosamine.

**1.** [Joint supplements for dogs: The helpful vs. the hype](https://www.dvm360.com/view/joint-supplements-dogs-helpful-vs-hype) Sarah J. Wooten, DVM